# 'RequestsCookieJar' object is not callable

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365, shareplum

Hi stackoverflow community!

I'm trying to authenticate in SharePoint using `Office365` from `shareplum`.

I'm able to get a `jar of cookies` successfully:

```
authcookie = Office365('https://enterprise.sharepoint.com'
username='user@enterprise.com', password='*****').GetCookies()
```

but then when I do:

```
site = Site('https://enterprise.sharepoint.com/sites/my_site/', version=Version.v2016, auth=authcookie)
```

I get the following error:

> "TypeError: 'RequestsCookieJar' object is not callable"

Can anyone please give me an hand with this? :)

Many thanks in advance!